# json parser error in salesforce restapi

Tags: apexrest

I have written the apex rest api . i need to insert the data into object.i will be getting the response in json format i need capture the data and insert into attribute object. i will be getting the response as follow `"lineitems" :[{"name1":"band","value1": "optisol"}]` after capturing the data. once the data is inserted ouput look as below

[image: once the data is inserted ouput look as below]

but we need to get single value.

Please find the below code help me how to fix it

```
if (body.id != null) {                      
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(params.get('lineItems',false));        
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        String name1;
        String value1;

        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'name1')) {
             // Get the value.
             parser.nextToken();
             name1= parser.getText();
        }
        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'value1')) {
            // Get the value.
            parser.nextToken();
            value1 = parser.getText();
        }

        Attribute__c atrb= createAttributeItem(name1,value1, body.id);
        insert(atrb);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: You are getting more in your JSON response than just a name and a value.  Try using system.debug(params.get('lineItems',false)) at the top of your outer if() block to see exactly what's in the JSON.  This should help you determine what you need to change.

Comment: jacson thanks for the response as . i cannot the debug for the restapi i was not able to see them